# Android Studio and gradle Error UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have this issue with my gradle project in Android Studio. When I do play, I have this error, but when I do the Clean and Rebuild, it does not show any error.

Error when I run

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":{},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536","position":{},"original":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:501)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:501)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:276)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:276)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:490)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:490)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:167)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:167)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)"}
```

Here's my gradle file config. I think the error comes here.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        //maven { url 'http://dt-imac-ba-032:8082/nexus/content/repositories/legacy/' }
        flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
        maven {
            url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
        }
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        //maven { url 'http://dt-imac-ba-032:8082/nexus/content/repositories/legacy/' }
        flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
        maven {
            url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
        }
        maven { url 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public' }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile project(':qRCodeReaderViewlib')
    compile ('com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview:swipelistview:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'


    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    signingConfigs {
        // debug {
        //    storeFile file("../keystore/sam.keystore")
        //}
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
                //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

}
```

In the qRCodeReaderViewlib

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/core.jar')
}
```

Where is the error ?

Comment: Why is `flatDir { dirs 'libs' }` in your `buildscript`? Remove all `flatDirs`. Try not to use **any** jars. Also, **please** upgrade you Android SDK, and other plugins, you should be targeting API 22, compiling with API 22 and your build tools should be 22.0.1.

Comment: I do this changes and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I would highly suggest trying to avoid using multidex. @exequielc Your project does not look like it has that many dependencies anyways.

Comment: I know but is the only way that my project can run

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this error occurs when you are using some libraries more than once
in this case maybe in "qRCodeReaderViewlib" some of your app libraries like supportlibrary have been added before

Comment: please upvote and accept the answer if worked for you

Answer (score 0):

If you're making any changes, you need to do it in app level build.gradle, not in top root level build.gradle. For example, if you're adding any support library, add it in build.gradle which you find in your app, not in build.gradle in the top level root.